# Display Date Difference in days in the Html.textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I have a two text boxes 'Start Date' and 'End Date' textboxes.I am using DatePicker control to select the date. I would like to display the date difference in 'Days' in third textbox when End Date gets selected automatically. Please let me know.

Thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate timespan in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141136/calculate-timespan-in-javascript)

Comment: That question asks for the result in hours and minutes, but you should be able to adapt it for days quite easily. Though if you do it in the code behind you can use the `TimeSpan` class (the result of differencing two `DateTime` objects) which will give you the days "for free".

Answer (score 0):

nav,

it's definately a javascript/jquery solution that's required.

you could try (in your endDate blur event):

```
$('#endDate').blur(function() {
    var diff = dateDiff($('#sttDate').val(), $('#endDate').val());
    // then do something with diff
});

function dateDiff(startDate, endDate) {
    return endDate.getDate() - startDate.getDate();
}
```

however, altho this will give an integer value of the difference in days, it will ignore the hours segment, therefore will not account for portions of days.

there are lots of 'good' to indifferent js resources that deal with date arithmetic. 
the good ones give insight, rather than answers. a google search on 'date arithmetic javascript' may (or may not) garner  worthwhile results.

happy hunting..

**[edit]** -  you may also want to look at http://api.jquery.com/focus/