# Validation Controls Number of Days Between 2 Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, datetime

I have two textboxes, txtStartDate, txtEndDate that allows users to choose a date for in the format (dd/mm/yyyy).  I need to be able to create a validator that checks to see if the number of days between these two user selected dates is 45 days or less.  Can I use one of the Validator controls like Range or Compare or do I have to create a custom validator?  Any examples would be very helpful.

Comment: I decided to delete my answer, because you're just to lazy to contribute even with a small attempt. If you don't change that, you're no good for this kind of site or anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx):

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="StartEndDiffValidator"
       ValidateEmptyText="true"
       ClientValidationFunction="StartEndValidate"
       OnServerValidate="StartEndValidate"
       Display="Dynamic"
       ErrorMessage="Timespan between start and end must be exactly 45 days"
       runat="server"/>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141159/284240) will lead you to the `ClientValidationFunction`.

Always implement also a serverside validation:

```
void StartEndValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    DateTime startDate;
    DateTime endDate;
    bool isStartDate = DateTime.TryParse(txtStartDate.Text, out startDate);
    bool isEndDate   = DateTime.TryParse(txtEndDate.Text, out endDate);
    if(isStartDate && isEndDate)
    {
        int days = (endDate - startDate ).Days;
        args.IsValid = days == 45;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

You could also use  [`CompareValidators`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx) with `Operator` property set to `ValidationCompareOperator.DataTypeCheck` and [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type.aspx)=Date to ensure that a date was entered in both.

Comment: If you can give me detailed examples it would be very helpful, like what the CustomValidator should look like as well as the Javascript function.

Comment: @ScrumMaster: I've added more details on the customvalidator markup and the server validate. I've currently not the time to show you a possible javascript implementation. Try it yourself with the link i've provided(either [jQuery date input](http://jonathanleighton.com/projects/date-input/#date-formatting) or [Matt Kruse date functions](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this block:

```
Dim st As String = txtClientSerStartTime.Text
Dim et As String = txtClientSerEndTime.Text
Dim time1 As DateTime
DateTime.TryParse(st, time1)
Dim ts1 As New TimeSpan(time1.Hour, time1.Minute, time1.Second)

Dim time As DateTime
DateTime.TryParse(et, time)
Dim ts As New TimeSpan(time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second)

Dim dur As TimeSpan = ts - ts1
Dim unit As Decimal = dur.Hours 

If unti = 45 Then
    'do something'
Else
    'do something'
End If
```