# jqPlot, plot date on xaxis and time on yaxis

Tags: c#, coffeescript, jqplot

I'm trying to plot using jqPlot the amount of time it takes for someone to complete something. On the xaxis I have the dates displaying correctly. However, on the yaxis I want to show the hour, minutes, seconds. No matter what I try it doesn't show correctly.

The screen capture belows shows the ticks mapping on the yaxis.

[image]

Here's the CoffeeScript...

```
    $.jqplot(
        "elemid"
        [["2013-02-01 01:30:28 AM", 97640000],["2013-02-01 01:31:38 AM", 166270000]]
        axes:
            xaxis:
                min: data.XAxisMin
                max: data.XAxisMax
                tickInterval: "1 month"
                tickOptions:
                    formatString: "%b %#d"
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
            yaxis:
                min: 0
                #tickOptions:
                     #formatString: "%#Mm"
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer
                #renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
        highlighter:
            show: true
            sizeAdjust: 7.5
        series:
            lineWidth: 4
            label: series.Label
            markerOptions: 
                style: "square"
    )
```

Here's the CoffeeScript converted to JavaScript...

```
$.jqplot("elemid", [["2013-02-01 01:30:28 AM", 97640000], ["2013-02-01 01:31:38 AM", 166270000]], {
  axes: {
    xaxis: {
      min: data.XAxisMin,
      max: data.XAxisMax,
      tickInterval: "1 month",
      tickOptions: {
        formatString: "%b %#d"
      },
      renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
    },
    yaxis: {
      min: 0,
      tickRenderer: $.jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer
    }
  },
  highlighter: {
    show: true,
    sizeAdjust: 7.5
  },
  series: {
    lineWidth: 4,
    label: series.Label,
    markerOptions: {
      style: "square"
    }
  }
});
```

I have created a jsfiddle but, I can't seem to get it to run. I've never used jsfiddle before so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong...

http://jsfiddle.net/uM8yu/5/

I've tried the DateAxisRenderer on the yaxis but, the time is not really a date/time per-se but just the hours, minutes, seconds it has take someone to complete.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Could you put the code please?

Comment: @Jason I can't compile your coffeescript somehow, can you [convert](http://js2coffee.org/) it to Javascript?

Comment: I updated my question with both the CoffeeScript and compiled JavaScript.

Comment: Can you put your working code on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle. I can't get it to run though but, i'm sure it's a novice mistake with jsfiddle since i've never used it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are configuring your `yaxis`, you also need to specify the `tickOptions`:

```
tickOptions: {
    formatter: function(format, value){
        return MillisecondsToDuration(value);
    }
}
```

What this will do is execute the `MillisecondsToDuration` method (adapted from [Calculate timespan in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141136/calculate-timespan-in-javascript)) each time a tick is rendered.

```
function MillisecondsToDuration(n) {
    var dtm = new Date();
    dtm.setTime(n);

    var hours = Math.floor(n / 3600000);
    var minutes = dtm.getMinutes();
    var seconds = dtm.getSeconds();

    return $.jqplot.sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', hours, minutes, seconds);        
}
```

The above method assumes that your time values are in milliseconds - you will need to adjust this if not. The `%02d` means that each value will be formatted with up to 2 leading zeros.