# How subtract 2 DateTimes to get DateTime result?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime, timespan

I use jquery Count up timer and it works in 1 line:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#count_up').countUp({ 'lang': 'en', 'format': 'day', 'sinceDate': '22/07/2008-00::00' });
});
```

So, this shows me the days, hours, minutes and seconds by `sinceDate`.

My Person model has `BirthDay` property. Which value should I pass to timer instead of  **"22/07/2008-00::00"** to calculate how much time Person live?

For example,  `BirthDay` is **20/02/2013 05:07:24**. And now date is: **23/02/2013-05:07:24**.

jquery `countUp()` will give to me: **3 days, 0 hour, 0 minutes, 0 seconds.**

How calculate `BirthDay` and `DateTime.Now` difference to pass counter? 
I need 2 DateTime difference that is in DateTime type.

**Edit:**

When I use only `BirthDay` in the `countUp()`, there is always 12 hours difference. For example, 12 hours, 5 minutes. But must be only 5 minutes. I don't understand this 12 hours difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a timespan/range

Have a look at

[Calculate timespan in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141136/calculate-timespan-in-javascript)

Comment: I find my bugs.   
BirthDay.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy-hh:mm:ss")  gives me hours in 12 AM/PM. But I need 24 hour clock. How can I take Time in 24 hour clock from BirthDay?

Comment: Probably I find answer. All was this: not 'hh', I should use 'HH'